# Device management tools for IOT/M2M which supports telecom and IOT devices

Tags: iot, telecommunication, 4g, device-management

Finding for the tools which will support the device management in the IOT/M2M.
The tool capability expectation is to monitor and manage all device types including switches,routers(mainly MPLS 4G Router) and gateways in telecom, Smart Home hubs, sensors and appliances M2M devices, smart power and water metering devices, health care devices and more.

Kindly let me know any such tools available in the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We (Cumulocity) offer an out-of-the-box device management.
Free trial account is here: http://www2.softwareag.com/corporate/products/internet_of_things/default.aspx

User guide is here: http://cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/device-management/

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion